# Confirm delete using swal on laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel-5.8, sweetalert

I got some troubles when using swal to confirm delete, I do not know how to make it work

here is my blade view file:

```
<form action="{{ route('user.destroy', $us->id)}}" method="post">
        @method('DELETE')
        @csrf
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

and the script using swal

```
  <script>
        //== Class definition
        var SweetAlert2Demo = function() {

            //== Demos
            var initDemos = function() {
                $('.btn-danger').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    swal({
                        title: 'Are you sure?',
                        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                        type: 'warning',
                        buttons:{
                            confirm: {
                                text : 'Yes, delete it!',
                                className : 'btn btn-success'
                            },
                            cancel: {
                                visible: true,
                                className: 'btn btn-danger'
                            }
                        }
                    }).then((Delete) => {
                        if (!Delete) {
                           e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    });
                });
            };

            return {
                //== Init
                init: function() {
                    initDemos();
                },
            };
        }();

        //== Class Initialization
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            SweetAlert2Demo.init();
        });
    </script>
```

the version of swal is https://sweetalert.js.org not https://sweetalert2.github.io/

And I'm using route resource on laravel 5.8
thanks you!

Comment: swal is not working??

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to dealing with delete button when it combine with swal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update in case of Loops**

<strike>You should give an `id` to your form and then in the `swal` callback submit the form by using the ID</strike>

```
<form action="{{ route('user.destroy', $us->id)}}" method="post" id="yourFormId">
```

Your JS Click button is almost same. Just some small change in the Swal JS Callback Method

```
        $('.btn-danger').click(function(e) {
                var $form =  $(this).closest("form"); //Get the form here.
                e.preventDefault();
                   swal({
                        title: 'Are you sure?',
                        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                        type: 'warning',
                        buttons:{
                            confirm: {
                                text : 'Yes, delete it!',
                                className : 'btn btn-success'
                            },
                            cancel: {
                                visible: true,
                                className: 'btn btn-danger'
                            }
                        }
                    }).then((Delete) => {
                        console.log(Delete); //This will be true when delete is clicked
                        if (Delete) {
                           $form.submit(); //Submit your Form Here. 
                           //$('#yourFormId').submit(); //Use same Form Id to submit the Form.
                        }
                    });
        });
```

Comment: thanks for your help, It really work. However, if I have many record, it always delete the first record in my table because I'm using for loop to create user table therefore all form will have same id.
Do you have any ideal to solve this problem?

Comment: @TùngNguyễn I have updated the answer in case of loops. You do not need to specify the id of form in this case. Notice how I have used `$form` in JS

Answer (score 0):

Use GET method instead of POST.
And no need to use button or combine anything.
Try this example,which always works with my all projects.
As
Use anchor tag, Not button

```
<a class="btn btn-action text-danger" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="deletefunction({{$your_id}})"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

Add Script As,

```
<script>
var deletefunction = function(id){
        swal({ 
            title: "Are you sure you want to Delete this?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            preConfirm: function(result) {
                window.location.href = '{{url('/your_route/delete')}}/'+id;
            },
            allowOutsideClick: false
        });
    };
</script>
```